# How to calculate SHA256 of a string

Tags: linux, hash, openssl, sha256, sha

Given a string in linux `str`, how can I calculate SHA256 (in size of 32 bytes) of this string ?
I looking for a way such then if I will compare this result to `openssl dgst -sha256 str.txt` (Assuming the file `str.txt` contains the string `str`).

I know that `sha256sum` do it, but i don't sure how to require the result to be 32 bytes.

Comment: Did you try it? If yes, did you get anything else than 32 bytes (256 bits)? Usually a SHA256 should have exactly that size.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf str | sha256sum | cut -c-64
8c25cb3686462e9a86d2883c5688a22fe738b0bbc85f458d2d2b5f3f667c6d5a
```

`printf str` prints "str" without any newline characters. `sha256sum` computes the sha256 and outputs it followed by blanks and hyphen. `cut -c-64` is there to make sure that only the first 64 hex characters of the hash are printed.

If you need the raw bytes (not the hex encoded bytes), you can append `xxd -r -p` to the pipeline. It will convert hexadecimal strings into raw binary.

The result matches that of `openssl`:

```
$ printf str | openssl dgst -sha256 -
SHA2-256(stdin)= 8c25cb3686462e9a86d2883c5688a22fe738b0bbc85f458d2d2b5f3f667c6d5a
```